# Encryption of Docx File in Python

Tags: python, encryption, aes, docx

```
from docx import Document

from Crypto.Cipher import AES

document = Document('test.docx')

allText = ""

for docpara in document.paragraphs:

  allText+=(docpara.text)

key="1234567891011121"

cipher=AES.new(key,AES.MODE_ECB) 

msg=cipher.encrypt(allText)
```

I want to encrypt a Docx file in python.But when i run this code:

raise TypeError("Object type %s cannot be passed to C code" % type(data))

TypeError: Object type  cannot be passed to C code

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: You aren't encrypting a Word file with that code. You are only encrypting *some* of the context you read from it. The file remains unprotected. Word files already support cryptographic encryption using AES and cryptographic signing.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
>>> from Crypto.Cipher import AES
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>>
>>> key = b'Sixteen byte key'
>>> iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
>>> cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
>>> msg = iv + cipher.encrypt(b'Attack at dawn')
```

I think your key needs to be converted to bytes first, and the object to be encrypted too. Notice the `b'` before both.

You also need to add an initialization vector (iv) to use for the encryption.